# What's the difference in meaning between "in the north of the city" and "in the north in the city"?

Tags: difference

I want to know if the two phrases are the same, or not.

If not, what are the meanings of each one?

Thank you.

Comment: The first means the north part of the city.  The second I wound interpret as two separate phases "In the North, in the city".

Answer (score 1):

"In the north of the city" refers to the northern part of the city. This sentence is fine on its own.

"In the north in the city" doesn't really work to be honest, I understand what you mean as a native English (British) speaker but I don't think that this is grammatically correct.

You can say "in the north, in the city", the comma however changes the meaning slightly. (Basically it now does not mean you are in the north part of the city, but rather that you are in the north somewhere, somewhere in a city).